# Icon-72,icon-small,icon-small-50,icon.png problem

Tags: icons

I have created a universal application(iphone/ipad) which is compatible with iOS3/iOS4. It was running fine and showing only one icon when I was using just one icon.png.

When I added Icon-72.png,icon-Small.png and Icon-Small-50.png to resource folder then it started to show 3 app icons on home screen in iphone simulator 4.2 and ipad simulator 4.2. While it shows two icons on home screen in ipad simulator 3.2..And it shows only one icon in iphone simulator 4.0 and 4.1. To fix it, I created CFbundleIconFiles and used correct naming convention for icon but it still shows the same problem.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you changed the Bundle ID so when you deployed you saw another version of the app. Just remove the apps with the old bundle IDs.